# maven PMD plugin generates xml which has wrong xml format

Tags: jenkins, maven-3, maven-plugin, pmd

I am running pmd using maven in a separate jenkins build

```
/tools/apache-maven-3.0.4/bin/mvn  pmd:pmd --settings $Settings > /logfiles/pmdResults.$Job 2>&1
```

The result xml is not correctly formatted. for some of the violations, it does not have end tag of violations. Hence jenkins is not able to parse the xml.

Example XML

```
<file name="/home/bhebbar/TestProj/src/main/java/com/hebbar/MyClass.java">
<violation beginline="20" endline="20" begincolumn="1" endcolumn="22" rule="UnusedImports" ruleset="Best Practices" package="com.hebbar" class="MyClass" externalInfoUrl="https://pmd.github.io/pmd-6.0.1/pmd_rules_java_bestpractices.html#unusedimports" priority="4">
Avoid unused imports such as 'osmdb.common'
</violation>
<violation beginline="21" endline="21" begincolumn="1" endcolumn="35" rule="UnusedImports" ruleset="Best Practices" package="com.hebbar" class="MyClass" externalInfoUrl="https://pmd.github.io/pmd-6.0.1/pmd_rules_java_bestpractices.html#unusedimports" priority="4">
Avoid unused imports such as 'com.sort.filtersort'
</violation>
<violation beginline="50" endline="55" begincolumn="12" endcolumn="56" rule="UnnecessaryModifier" ruleset="Code Style" package="com.hebbar" class="MyClass" method="getTProfiles" externalInfoUrl="https://pmd.github.io/pmd-6.0.1/pmd_rules_java_codestyle.html#unnecessarymodifier" priority="3">
<violation beginline="68" endline="68" begincolumn="12" endcolumn="76" rule="UnnecessaryModifier" ruleset="Code Style" package="com.hebbar" class="MyClass" method="getTProfile" externalInfoUrl="https://pmd.github.io/pmd-6.0.1/pmd_rules_java_codestyle.html#unnecessarymodifier" priority="3">
<violation beginline="83" endline="88" begincolumn="12" endcolumn="56" rule="UnnecessaryModifier" ruleset="Code Style" package="com.hebbar" class="MyClass" method="getAProfiles" externalInfoUrl="https://pmd.github.io/pmd-6.0.1/pmd_rules_java_codestyle.html#unnecessarymodifier" priority="3">
<violation beginline="101" endline="101" begincolumn="12" endcolumn="78" rule="UnnecessaryModifier" ruleset="Code Style" package="com.hebbar" class="MyClass" method="getAProfile" externalInfoUrl="https://pmd.github.io/pmd-6.0.1/pmd_rules_java_codestyle.html#unnecessarymodifier" priority="3">
<violation beginline="103" endline="106" begincolumn="12" endcolumn="64" rule="UnnecessaryModifier" ruleset="Code Style" package="com.hebbar" class="MyClass" method="getCProfileName" externalInfoUrl="https://pmd.github.io/pmd-6.0.1/pmd_rules_java_codestyle.html#unnecessarymodifier" priority="3">
<violation beginline="108" endline="112" begincolumn="12" endcolumn="57" rule="UnnecessaryModifier" ruleset="Code Style" package="com.hebbar" class="MyClass" method="getCProfileDetails" externalInfoUrl="https://pmd.github.io/pmd-6.0.1/pmd_rules_java_codestyle.html#unnecessarymodifier" priority="3">
<violation beginline="114" endline="116" begincolumn="12" endcolumn="59" rule="UnnecessaryModifier" ruleset="Code Style" package="com.hebbar" class="MyClass" method="getCProfileDetails" externalInfoUrl="https://pmd.github.io/pmd-6.0.1/pmd_rules_java_codestyle.html#unnecessarymodifier" priority="3">
<violation beginline="119" endline="119" begincolumn="2" endcolumn="2" rule="EmptyStatementNotInLoop" ruleset="Error Prone" package="com.hebbar" class="MyClass" externalInfoUrl="https://pmd.github.io/pmd-6.0.1/pmd_rules_java_errorprone.html#emptystatementnotinloop" priority="3">
An empty statement (semicolon) not part of a loop
</violation>
</file>
```

and i got the following error

```
pmd.xml failed due to an exception:

org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The element type "violation" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</violation>".
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.digester3.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1642)
    at org.apache.commons.digester3.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1701)
    at hudson.plugins.pmd.parser.PmdParser.parse(PmdParser.java:70)
    at hudson.plugins.analysis.core.AbstractAnnotationParser.parse(AbstractAnnotationParser.java:53)
    at hudson.plugins.analysis.core.FilesParser.parseFile(FilesParser.java:323)
    at hudson.plugins.analysis.core.FilesParser.parseFiles(FilesParser.java:281)
    at hudson.plugins.analysis.core.FilesParser.parserCollectionOfFiles(FilesParser.java:232)
    at hudson.plugins.analysis.core.FilesParser.invoke(FilesParser.java:201)
    at hudson.plugins.analysis.core.FilesParser.invoke(FilesParser.java:31)
    at hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper.call(FilePath.java:2484)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:328)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Could you please help me understand if some flag needs to be set while running pmd? how can i get this parsed correctly by jenkins?

Comment: What version of the PMD Maven Plugin are you using?

Comment: Can you post (at least part of) your pom.xml? Do you use any special configuration for the maven-pmd-plugin? Do you use a custom ruleset?

Comment: @adangel There is nothing related to pmd in pom.xml. i just want to use default plugin settings. hence giving it in cmd line. i know it is using pmd plugin 3.9.0   [INFO] --- maven-pmd-plugin:3.9.0:pmd (default-cli) @